What's a modern term for sucker or sap?
I'm looking for a noun for somone who allows others to take advantage of them, similar in meaning to "sucker" or "sap" but less dated. For example, what would you call the one person who does work on a group project or the single responsible person among a bunch of freeloaders?

What makes you think sucker or sap are not understood or used by younger generations?

Which younger generations? Where?

Adjectives, offered here, are 'gullible' and 'naive'; if you require a noun only, please indicate this. Have you tried looking in a thesaurus? Pushover is offered here, in an earlier thread.

I'm in my 50s in the US, and "sucker" and "sap" sound to me like things that would be said in a black and white movie like Guys and Dolls. Google Books Ngram Viewer confirms that their usage in the last century peaked in the 1920s and 1930s. I'll rephrase my question.

Answers go in the answer box: comments providing answers will be removed. Comments have been moved to chat; do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Where I hail from, that would be a chump:

chump noun
informal : a person who is easily tricked : a stupid or foolish person Source:
Merriam-Webster

You can find sample usages at Merriam-Webster’s How to Use chump in a Sentence. Here are a couple:

The former Gladiators who felt exploited by the show don’t want
to be seen as chumps.
Stuck working in the city like a chump while your friends make
their weekend treks to coastal properties?

Wiktionary list these as synonyms of chump:

(a gullible person): gull, sucker, dupe, sap, dummy, patsy, pigeon


Is "chump" really more modern that "sucker"? I've used "sucker" all the time, but I only heard "chump" in P G Wodehouse novels.

I use chump all the time.  "Single-word-requests are for chumps."   I don't think Wikitionary has captured the essence of the word, BTW.

I can’t say for sure whether it’s more “modern”, but it’s certainly more popular now than when Wodehouse uttered it.

@TinfoilHat What does your local dialect say about chump change?

@TimR — Do you mean do we say chump change? Yes. It tracks with a chump in rise in popularity.

The only noun I'd consider appropriate here is doormat, in the metaphorical usage, which 'feels' less dated† to me:

doormat [noun]
...
[2] a submissive person who allows others to dominate them.

to put up with such treatment you must be either a saint or a doormat_


[ODE; courtesy of Google.]
Other synonyms, like 'patsy' and 'pushover', feel also too dated and/or too hypernymic. Though 'doormat' in the metaphorical usage cannot itself claim to be modern†; The Online Etymology Dictionary has it dating from at the latest 1861.

I agree. Chump as used by Wodehouse or 1950s comics has no overtones of compliance, rather of foolishness, lack of judgement, and incomprehension.

A rube is a naive or inexperienced person. It would fit well for someone who is easily taken advantage of, although it might not be a good fit for the one person in charge of a group project, since it somewhat suggests a lack of intellect (who you probably wouldn't want to put in charge). The term sounds somewhat antiquated as it first saw widespread popularity in the 1920s, but has seen a major resurgence since the 2000s.
Another term is to call someone a mark, which is the intended victim of a con. This suggests that the person is easily targeted by people trying to take advantage of them. It would suggest perhaps a more nefarious and explicit attempt to take advantage of someone, rather than passively foisting off group work, as it suggests a deliberate action. If someone repeatedly falls for different scams, for example, calling them a mark would be appropriate.

Rube sounds a bit dated too. Looking at Green's examples, the ones from the last 50 years are either referencing past times, or in political journalism which isn't really a sphere where you get the latest slang. Ben Hecht (1894-1964) writing in 1963 wouldn't be my guide to 21st century slang. Mark is more of a term of art so still sounds more current.

@StuartF Google ngrams shows that "rube" is almost as commonly used today as it was at its peak in the 1920s, which is even more popular than its 1950-60s resurgence - although it's not clear how the popularity of the name Rube confounds the data. I thought "rube" seemed a little old fashioned at first too but was surprised by the strong and recent uptick in usage.

Pushover: Someone who is easy to push around and to take advantage of; someone who lets themselves be picked on or bullied without defending or standing up for themselves.
This word is certainly not dated. One can easily find many tens of tweets with pushover (used in OP's specific sense) on just 2024-12-11 alone.

Some actual modern terms:
Sheeple is a derogatory term for the mass of people who are stupid and easily led: it's a portmanteau of sheep and people. It's made most dictionaries, e.g. Cambridge which defines it as "people who copy what other people do or believe what they are told and do not think for themselves." It doesn't have a common singular form, although "sheeperson" is a jokey coinage and you sometimes see "a sheeple" (see this ELU question).
Cuck has evolved from a short word for cuckold (a man whose wife cheats on him), via a man who has a sexual fetish for watching his wife have sex with other men (stereotypically an under-endowed white man whose wife pleasures black men), to a general term of abuse for weak men: it's popular in pick-up/incel/MGTOW and similar misogynistic cultures, and used by right-wing Americans to attack liberals who are seen as weak, subservient, and feminine. (RationalWiki, and Wikipedia article Cuckservative)
NPC is a term from video games referring to a non-player character, typically a computer controlled figure in a RPG who'll wander around saying the same thing every time a player interacts with them. Hence it's used as a term of abuse by right-wing Americans for people who can't think for themselves and who parrot left-wing talking points, or who generally act like brainles, passive video game characters (as opposed to video game characters who're trying to kill you). (Wikipedia, RationalWiki)

Is sheeple still used non-ironically?

These are all poor suggestions, but ”Cuck” in particular is one of those words that is so loaded that you should never use in a general conversation.  First off, it’s a sexually-based insult, which should be enough reason to avoid it in casual speech. But second,  as you touch on, it’s something of a shibboleth among the asshole end of right-wing politics - use of this word will make people think you’re one of them, which will normally result in them dismissing any argument you’re making at the time.

Tool might work for you. From Dictionary.com:

tool (n.)
a person manipulated by another for the latter's own ends; cat's-paw.

Note that I have also heard it used to describe someone who is generally unintelligent or obnoxious.

A warning: In the variety of English I speak (Irish), calling someone a “tool” only has the meaning of “someone unintelligent or obnoxious”.  I also feel that this meaning of “idiot” is also more common in British English than the literal “manipulated” one.


easy mark (n.)
One easily imposed upon, duped, or overcome
M-W


easy game in British English or easy mark (n.)
Informal
A person who is easily deceived or taken advantage of.
Collins


An easy mark (and its variants) are quite old, but are still in use.

Pris's mother had landed on his da's list with the magazine scam. That
made her an easy mark for his other cons.
Patricia Rice; The
Crystal Palace (2022)


Scareware
...The hackers are looking for a response that singles out a target as gullible and easily fooled. The target's response
could identify the target as an easy "mark".
Luis Ayala;
Cybersecurity for Hospitals and Healthcare Facilities: (2016)


To offer a few alternate terms for sucker or sap: persons who are prone to enabling others to easily take advantage of them at their own expense, may be consequently perceived as a bleeding heart by some, if not treated as a tool by those who may also call said persons an easy mark. One who enables others to overstep personal boundaries in a significant or notable capacity may be considered as a pushover, or more unkindly called a doormat. Those who are easily manipulated into the bidding of others by dishonest means may be derogatorily known as a dupe or a chump.
Bouncing between synonyms and antonyms in a thesaurus is a fantastic way to find increasingly entertaining-yet-obscure ways of approaching such topical content as the interplay between such cadgers and gulls.
I will concede that a couple of these are more correctly considered idioms or even colloquialisms more than proper nouns. Their usage however is typically in accordance with a conventional noun, so I hope you may see fit to forgive my flexibility in linguistic decorum.
In relation to the issue of linguistic modernity, I would suggest that rather than any factor of generational dialect, the familiarity of any given person with any one of these terms may have a stronger correlation with a given person's personal experience with victimization and fraud: if you're not a bleeding heart who's been duped like a chump for being an easy mark, and you're not an unkind soul who sees people as pushovers and doormats, then you would have little reason to be intimately familiar with the definitions of such terms. Enough time spent surrounded by English-speaking culture however, may allow the scrupulously observant to absorb such terms through cultural-osmosis.

Most of these are given in earlier answers.

Possibly simp, although that has the specific connotation of a man trying desperately to earn the favor of a woman in hopes of a sexual relationship, when it is obvious to everyone (except him) that she is not interested.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simp
